# How to load UIViewController XIB inside another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, viewcontroller

I am trying to add a `UIViewController` **XIB** to an existing `ViewController`, trying to create this:

[image]

I have a simple `ViewController` and then I made a `UIView` with **XIB**... and now I am trying to use it in the new `ViewController`:

```
    let myVC = XIBViewController(nibName: "XIBViewController.xib", bundle: nil)
    self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I make it as small as in the image, with the `BaseViewController` still visible?

Comment: you want it as a pop?

Answer (score 1):

Replace ( Remove `.xib` )

```
let myVC = P3XIBViewController(nibName: "P3XIBViewController.xib", bundle: nil)
```

with

```
let myVC = P3XIBViewController(nibName: "P3XIBViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: The view still does not show up, I get this: Warning: Attempt to present <p2_p3_movement_TEST.P3XIBViewController: 0x10350bdb0> on <p2_p3_movement_TEST.ViewController: 0x10400b400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Don't present it inside `viewDidLoad` as it's too early

Comment: Ok, it worked now... but how can I make it as small as in the image in my question?